# Error to settext to a edittext inside switch statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I am attempting to use a settext for an edittext. I have this code because I need to use the afterTextChanged() in multiple edittext. If I use a setText inside a case: the App crashes but it works correcty outside in a onClick of a button.

```
    public Button btn;
    public EditText et1, et2, et3;
    private int whoHasFocus = 0;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing2, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ladoA);
        et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et1.addTextChangedListener(this);
        et2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ladoB);
        et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et2.addTextChangedListener(this);
        et3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ladoC);
        et3.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et3.addTextChangedListener(this);

        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                et1.setText("Works correctly.");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        switch (whoHasFocus) {
            case 1:
                et2.setText("It does not work.");
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ladoA:
                whoHasFocus = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.ladoB:
                whoHasFocus = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.ladoC:
                whoHasFocus = 3;
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the log:

```
10-01 11:47:19.202    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-01 11:47:21.855    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 234K, 35% free 11382K/17256K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
10-01 11:47:21.885    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 20.760MB for 6998416-byte allocation
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4143/example.test.com.testApp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 25% free 18209K/24092K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 40ms
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 371: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 373: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
10-01 11:47:21.935    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/view/View;.invalidate:VZ
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ method requires 40+20+20=80 bytes, fp is 0x57102338 (56 left)
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ expanding stack end (0x57102300 to 0x57102000)
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp I/dalvikvm﹕ Shrank stack (to 0x57102300, curFrame is 0x57107d20)
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-01 11:47:28.252    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e37ac8)
10-01 11:47:28.342    4141-4141/example.test.com.testApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10849)
            at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4975)
            at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4966)
            at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:8060)
            at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:10023)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
            at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:116)
            at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:127)
            at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4092)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp.Testing2.afterTextChanged(Testing2.java:62)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7982)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3924)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
            at example.test.com.testApp
```

Comment: Please post the error that is output to Logcat when the app crashes.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Thaks for answering, I post it in another answer.

Comment: You should edit that into your original post, not create an answer

Comment: Thanks, I already did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the text in `afterTextChanged`, which is causing the same method to be called again, causing an infinite loop. Remove the listener, set the text, then add the listener back.

```
et2.removeTextChangedListener(this);
et2.setText("this will work");
et2.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the EditText's text inside afterTextChanged, which calls afterTextChanged again. This recursive call creates an infinite loop that leads to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

calling SetText inside OnTextChanged cause infinite loop.. 
You can set a condition to stop it:

```
if (et2.getText.equals(originalValue )) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    et2.setText("xxx");
    originalValue = et2.getText();
}
```